# Hide part of a div on click of a button on a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress plugin called contact form 7 to build a mailing list for a website that's coming soon (the client doesn't want us using mailchimp or other such services as they don't want the user getting ANY emails including the confirmation email that mailchimp sends anytime someone subscribes).

Anyway, i need the email field and the button to hide when the user clicks on "Notify me!" but i still want to show the "Thank you" message.

here's the screenshot of the form and the code.

[image]

[image]

and here's some code i added to hide the div but it hides everything including the "thank you" message.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.wpcf7-response-output').on('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#wpcf7-f128-p47-o1').toggle('hide');
    });
});
</script>
```

************ UPDATE ************

This might be silly but the solution was as simple as copy pasting the html from the code inspector on chrome and adding a div around the part i wanted to hide.

Comment: I don't understand why are you taking click event of `wpcf7-response-output` instead of `wpcf7-submit`? Secondly, You are toggling whole **div**. Message is its children div. So you need to hide specific email field and button only.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner that is correct. i had to change it to wpcf7-submit in order for it to work but that still doesn't solve my problem. i need the form to hide once the user hits submit but still want to show the "Thank you" message. the plugin only gives me a short code to paste and not the html code

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.wpcf7-response-output').on('click', function(event) { 
         jQuery('.wpcf7-form.sent').toggle('hide');
    });
});
</script>
```

Looks like you hid the wrong div maybe you can share a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co) ?